# Steps to create a movie with objects and cameras moved independently of each other in PyMOL

Tags: movie, pymol, position-independent-code

I have compiled open-source PyMOL v2.2.0a0 under Linux OS.

Reading [this webpage](https://pymol.org/animate.html) and seeing [this video](https://pymol.org/sites/default/files/movie_ray3.mpg), I tried the "*copy to object / new*" command on selections, moving them indipendently with the mouse in "*edit mode*", saving the state of the scene after each edit, but I can't interpolate between them.

In other words, I still can not understand how to realize a video like the one shown in that webpage.

Thank you for your attention,

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution in [this page](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/MovieSchool_5): ***object motions***—keeping the camera still, but moving the objects around the scene.

There is a working example:

```
# setup PyMOL for movies
reinitialize set matrix_mode, 1
set movie_panel, 1
set scene_buttons, 1
set cache_frames, 1
config_mouse three_button_motions, 1

# download the complex and setup it up fetch 1te1, async=0
extract AA, c. A
extract BB, c. B
color marine, AA
color grey, BB
as surface, BB
as cartoon, AA

# intialize the movie
mset 1 x410

# orient the scene
set_view (\
0.423117876, 0.061672822, 0.903973043,\
0.789699256, -0.514252067, -0.334546506,\
0.444237947, 0.855418444, -0.266292989,\
0.000107866, -0.000027858, -196.784057617,\
28.171787262, 70.919288635, 52.095287323,\
155.143981934, 238.418914795, -20.000000000 )

# move the inhibitor off the screeen
translate [0,0,100], object=AA

# first movie scene
frame 1
wizard message, "Let's watch the binder float it, while the camera doesn't move."
mview store, object=AA
mview store, object=BB

# 2 second pause for the user to catch up frame 60
mview store, object=AA
mview store, object=BB

# slide the inhibitor in from over the camera. :-)
frame 300
translate [0,0,-100], object=AA
mview store, object=AA
mview interpolate, object=AA

# store & wait 2 seconds...
frame 360
mview store, object=AA
mview store, object=BB
mview reinterpolate, object=AA
mview reinterpolate, object=BB

# 'explode' apart
frame 380
translate [-70, 70, 70], object=AA
translate [70, -70, -70], object=BB
mview store, object=AA
mview store, object=BB
mview reinterpolate, object=AA
mview reinterpolate, object=BB

mplay
```

You can save it in a .pml file (eg *script.pml*), in the default PyMOL path, to be able to call it with the command `@script.pml` inside PyMOL.

Here my [demo](https://youtu.be/0EwPqLuG6rU)